# What is the purpose of the SKI combinator calculus(or even lambda calculus)? What are some real life examples of its use?

Tags: algorithms, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I understand what it is, but I don't see how it is any use for algorithms or anything. Maybe I am missing something. I need someone to give me an example of how it can be used so I can understand it better.

Comment: There are several [esoteric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) programming languages based on combinatorial logic, e.g. [Unlambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlambda). See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Combinatory_logic_in_computing). You can find further information by exploring the links in the articles.

Answer (score 11):

The obvious application of the lambda calculus is any functional programming language (e.g., Lisp, ML, Haskell), and any language that supports anonymous functions.

As for combinator calculus, does there have to be a "real-world application"?  Turing machines, for example, are hardly ever used "in the real world" but they form the basis of the theory of computation.  One useful feature of combinator calculi is that they're simpler systems than, e.g., Turing machines. If you want to prove that some other system is Turing-complete, it might be easier to show how it can simulate combinators than to show it can simulate a Turing machine.

Comment: Of course, combinators *were* used in compilation of functional languages (though not the SKI calculus itself).

Comment: @cody Please post an answer about that! It's not something I know about so I'd rather not edit into my answer.

Comment: For example, Scala's type system has been shown to be Turing-complete by embedding the SK-calculus in it. I cannot even begin to imagine the absurd complexity of embedding a (Universal) Turing Machine. Ironically (given the name) Turinf-completeness is seldom shown with Turing Machines. SQL was shown to be TC by implementing a Cyclic Tag System, HTML+CSS with Rule 101, the Intel MMU by encoding a "Move, Branch if Zero, Decrement" instruction.

Comment: @JörgWMittag re: "*HTML+CSS with Rule 101*" did you mean "*Rule 110*"?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Of course, stupid typo. The code is here: https://github.com/elitheeli/stupid-machines

Answer (score 5):

I found SKI useful to understand some logical axioms.

For instance, a Hilbert-style axiomatization of (intuitionistic) implication is

$$
\begin{array}{l}
(a \rightarrow b \rightarrow c) \rightarrow (a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow a \rightarrow c 
\\
a \rightarrow (b \rightarrow a)
\end{array}
$$

The first time I saw these axioms, I wondered why on earth they should work. Sure, it's easy to check that they hold. But why should these be enough, i.e. why using these two postulates alone is enough to prove (through modus ponens) all the other implicational tautologies? Mystery... or is it?

Well, it turns out that every tautology must correspond to the type of some lambda-term, thanks to the Curry-Howard isomorphism. But said lambda term can be equivalently rewritten in term of combinators $S,K$ alone. So, the types of $S$ and $K$ must generate, through application, the types of any tautology. And indeed, the two axioms above are the most general types for $S$ and $K$.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Microsoft's LINQ (Language INtegrated Query). It makes extensive and quite direct use of lambda calculus to manipulate and transform expression trees. Probably the most complete and sophisticated example would be Linq2SQL (the SQL Server implementation) which efficiently performs complex transformations that segregate the portions of the expression tree that can be delegated to the database server.

This is hardly the first technology that allows queries that combine data from several sources, but it may well be the first one that automates the untangling of dependencies to leverage the bulk manipulation capabilities of database servers. It's not perfect (sometimes you have to help it out) but it does the grunt work very nicely and with an attention to detail you won't get from humans.

When you *do* have to help it out, understanding the calculus will take you a long way toward figuring out what's bothering it - so in addition to *What use is it?* there's your answer to *Why do I have to learn this when machines will do it for me?*